# How I add data from the Windows Form Aplication (text box) to Database Sql?

Tags: c#, sql, database, forms, textbox

I want to add data from TextBox to the database, but it does not work.

```
private void insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection Conectare = new SqlConnection();
    Conectare.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; 
        AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Cuvinte.mdf;
        Integrated Security=True;User    
       Instance=True ";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Tabel_Cuvinte(id,cuv_ger,cuv_eng)"+" VALUES (@id, @cuv_ger,@cuv_eng)", Conectare);

    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtnr.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@cuv_ger", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtger.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@cuv_eng", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value= txteng.Text;
    Conectare.Open();
    da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Conectare.Close();
}
```

Comment: If you put your code in a try  catch {}, are you getting an exception, with  Arvin s correction??

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtnr.Text;
```

with this

```
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtnr.Text);
```

Comment: Good idea, but when I click on the button it doesn't work. :(

Comment: What's the error? are you sure you assign the method to on click event?

Answer (score 0):

"Does not work" is a little ambiguous.  If you are getting an error or an exception, please post it.

1. Are you getting an error?
2. Does the button click fail to invoke the method above?
3. Does the method get called but then the insert isn't happening?

Additionally as Arvin suggests, convert the textbox value to an integer first.

Answer (score 0):

I also had fighted long time with same problem. And I saw many same questions & answers.

You're using |DataDirectory|.I assume you can get values from the DB file and you don't get error to run insert command but the values are not inserted into the DB file.

This is absolutely my private idea and my private conclusion is that this behavior is normal as  |DataDirectory| does. I mean a data file of an application should be protected from manipulation once after deployment. The 'Data' file should provide data inside the file so that we can read the data.

Therefore, I coded to create a localDB .MDF file (MS SQL 2014) from users' side so that my applications can utilize the localDB to write and read data. My application automatically downloads data from cloud server which are we need to update frequently.
On the other side, I put big and already fixed data into |DataDirectory| .MDF file, I mean inserted big data for read only and add the MDF file to my project before deployment.

Hope my experience helps..But, please keep in mind again that this is really my private opinion and I might be totally wrong and my experience is limited only to localDB. But again, I couldn't find a Microsoft's official document mentioning this behavior.

Do you have only 1 option like |DataDirectory|  ? Did this work to insert before? Is this code by you wrote on your own? If possible, try to find another option rather than |DataDirectory| to connect to the SQL database.
I use a cloud SQL server with IP address but I can't understand why you use |DataDirectory|. There might be many various options as connectionstrings to SQL Express.

Comment: And in my case, there's no / like |DataDirectory|Cuvinte.mdf; you can simply try.